# Link textboxes to expedia.com search

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

I am making a site which includes a widget to allow my users to search for hotels and flights on expedia.com. I have reviewed the expedia APIs, and they are beyond the scope of my project - I'm not looking to build a private label search using their apis, I just want to send the origin and destination cities to expedia.com, and have those two fields filled out by my users. Currently I am able to (occaisionally) use the flights.expedia.com and pass as a parameter two airport codes, however this is only working for flights, and requires my users to enter airport codes, which is not ideal. 
Is there a way to simply send the content of an origin and destination textbox on my site, to the origin and destination textboxes on expedia.com? Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this question is to make your form (which contains your search box) submit its values to Expedia's search results script.

To accomplish this, you first need to examine a similar search form on Expedia's site. Look at the `action` attribute of the form to find the target. Also note that you will need to add Expedia's domain name to the location, since you will be accessing it from your own site.

For example, if Expedia's form has an `action` equal to '/Home.htm', your form will need an action equal to "http://www.expedia.com/Home.htm". When a user submits your form, the data will be sent to Expedia's handler.

Next, you need to determine what fields to include in the form. To do this, you will need to test Expedia's form to see which fields are optional which throw an error when left blank. Make sure your form includes all of those fields, and name your fields with the same names that Expedia uses.

Finally, you will need to determine if Expedia's site will block forms posted from other domains. Some sites do, some don't. Only testing (or access to a knowledgeable source at Expedia) will tell. If your submission is not blocked, you will be able to submit data via your form and see results on Expedia's site.